# Strace syscall classes

Tags: strace

Strace allows

```
strace -e trace=$some_class
```

to specify a class of system calls to trace.

E.g.,

```
 strace -e trace=file
```

should trace all file-related system calls.

How can I find out which these are exactly? I'd like to get the full list of the system calls that belong to the `file` class.

Comment: I'd like to get the full list of the system calls that belong to the file class. These should include `open, openat, stat, lstat, fstatat, mkdir, mkdirat, unlink, unlinkat, etc.`. If I can extract it from strace or it source, the better. So far I've been having difficulties finding it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did a dig into the source code [strace 4.9](https://sourceforge.net/projects/strace/files/strace/4.9/) and found this:

```
{ 3,    TD|TF,  sys_open,               "open"      }, /* 5 */
{ 2,    TD|TF,  sys_creat,              "creat"     }, /* 8 */
{ 2,    TF, sys_link,                   "link"      }, /* 9 */
{ 1,    TF, sys_unlink,                 "unlink"    }, /* 10 */
{ 3,    TF|TP|SE|SI,    sys_execve,     "execve"    }, /* 11 */
{ 1,    TF, sys_chdir,                  "chdir"     }, /* 12 */
{ 3,    TF, sys_mknod,                  "mknod"     }, /* 14 */
{ 2,    TF, sys_chmod,                  "chmod"     }, /* 15 */
{ 3,    TF, sys_chown,                  "lchown"    }, /* 16 */
{ 2,    TF, sys_oldstat,                "oldstat"   }, /* 18 */
{ 5,    TF, sys_mount,                  "mount"     }, /* 21 */
{ 1,    TF, sys_umount,                 "oldumount" }, /* 22 */
{ 2,    TF, sys_utime,                  "utime"     }, /* 30 */
{ 2,    TF, sys_access,                 "access"    }, /* 33 */
{ 2,    TF, sys_rename,                 "rename"    }, /* 38 */
{ 2,    TF, sys_mkdir,                  "mkdir"     }, /* 39 */
{ 1,    TF, sys_rmdir,                  "rmdir"     }, /* 40 */
{ 1,    TF, sys_acct,                   "acct"      }, /* 51 */
{ 2,    TF, sys_umount2,                "umount"    }, /* 52 */
{ 1,    TF, sys_chroot,                 "chroot"    }, /* 61 */
{ 2,    TF, sys_symlink,                "symlink"   }, /* 83 */
{ 2,    TF, sys_oldlstat,               "oldlstat"  }, /* 84 */
{ 3,    TF, sys_readlink,               "readlink"  }, /* 85 */
{ 1,    TF, sys_uselib,                 "uselib"    }, /* 86 */
{ 2,    TF, sys_swapon,                 "swapon"    }, /* 87 */
{ 2,    TF, sys_truncate,               "truncate"  }, /* 92 */
{ 2,    TF, sys_statfs,                 "statfs"    }, /* 99 */
{ 2,    TF, sys_stat,                   "stat"      }, /* 106 */
{ 2,    TF, sys_lstat,                  "lstat"     }, /* 107 */
{ 1,    TF, sys_swapoff,                "swapoff"   }, /* 115 */
{ 4,    TF, sys_quotactl,               "quotactl"  }, /* 131 */
{ 3,    TF, sys_chown,                  "chown"     }, /* 182 */
{ 2,    TF, sys_getcwd,                 "getcwd"    }, /* 183 */
{ 3,    TF, sys_truncate64,             "truncate64"    }, /* 193 */
{ 2,    TF, sys_stat64,                 "stat64"    }, /* 195 */
{ 2,    TF, sys_lstat64,                "lstat64"   }, /* 196 */
{ 3,    TF, sys_chown,                  "lchown32"  }, /* 198 */
{ 3,    TF, sys_chown,                  "chown32"   }, /* 212 */
{ 2,    TF, sys_pivotroot,              "pivot_root"    }, /* 217 */
{ 5,    TF, sys_setxattr,               "setxattr"  }, /* 226 */
{ 5,    TF, sys_setxattr,               "lsetxattr" }, /* 227 */
{ 4,    TF, sys_getxattr,               "getxattr"  }, /* 229 */
{ 4,    TF, sys_getxattr,               "lgetxattr" }, /* 230 */
{ 3,    TF, sys_listxattr,              "listxattr" }, /* 232 */
{ 3,    TF, sys_listxattr,              "llistxattr"    }, /* 233 */
{ 2,    TF, sys_removexattr,            "removexattr"   }, /* 235 */
{ 2,    TF, sys_removexattr,            "lremovexattr"  }, /* 236 */
{ 3,    TF, sys_statfs64,               "statfs64"  }, /* 268 */
{ 2,    TF, sys_utimes,                 "utimes"    }, /* 271 */
{ 4,    TD|TF,  sys_openat,             "openat"    }, /* 295 */
{ 3,    TD|TF,  sys_mkdirat,            "mkdirat"   }, /* 296 */
{ 4,    TD|TF,  sys_mknodat,            "mknodat"   }, /* 297 */
{ 5,    TD|TF,  sys_fchownat,           "fchownat"  }, /* 298 */
{ 3,    TD|TF,  sys_futimesat,          "futimesat" }, /* 299 */
{ 4,    TD|TF,  sys_newfstatat,         "fstatat64" }, /* 300 */
{ 3,    TD|TF,  sys_unlinkat,           "unlinkat"  }, /* 301 */
{ 4,    TD|TF,  sys_renameat,           "renameat"  }, /* 302 */
{ 5,    TD|TF,  sys_linkat,             "linkat"    }, /* 303 */
{ 3,    TD|TF,  sys_symlinkat,          "symlinkat" }, /* 304 */
{ 4,    TD|TF,  sys_readlinkat,         "readlinkat"    }, /* 305 */
{ 3,    TD|TF,  sys_fchmodat,           "fchmodat"  }, /* 306 */
{ 3,    TD|TF,  sys_faccessat,          "faccessat" }, /* 307 */
{ 4,    TD|TF,  sys_utimensat,          "utimensat" }, /* 320 */
{ 6,    TD|TF,  sys_fanotify_mark,      "fanotify_mark" }, /* 339 */
{ 5,    TD|TF,  sys_name_to_handle_at,  "name_to_handle_at"}, /* 341 */
{ 5,    TD|TF,  sys_renameat2,          "renameat2" }, /* 353 */
```

`TF` stands for file related class of system calls used by `strace`.
Note that this example list is for **i386** architecture. The list might be different for other platforms.

And long names for classes:

```
/* Define these shorthand notations to simplify the syscallent files. */ 
#define TD TRACE_DESC 
#define TF TRACE_FILE 
#define TI TRACE_IPC 
#define TN TRACE_NETWORK 
#define TP TRACE_PROCESS 
#define TS TRACE_SIGNAL 
#define TM TRACE_MEMORY 
#define NF SYSCALL_NEVER_FAILS 
#define MA MAX_ARGS 
#define SI STACKTRACE_INVALIDATE_CACHE 
#define SE STACKTRACE_CAPTURE_ON_ENTER
```

Comment: For strace in 2024, looking at x86-64 specifically, it looks like the equivalent list is in [this file](https://github.com/strace/strace/blob/76cc8c5cc3a07a63d2a89dcee0f54dafae7c5319/src/linux/x86_64/syscallent.h), plus an additional list (shared across architectures) in [syscallent-common.h](https://github.com/strace/strace/blob/76cc8c5cc3a07a63d2a89dcee0f54dafae7c5319/src/linux/generic/syscallent-common.h).

Comment: And the [expanded list of abbreviations](https://github.com/strace/strace/blob/76cc8c5cc3a07a63d2a89dcee0f54dafae7c5319/src/sysent_shorthand_defs.h#L39), along with [some comments on what those classes mean](https://github.com/strace/strace/blob/76cc8c5cc3a07a63d2a89dcee0f54dafae7c5319/src/sysent.h#L21).